# XML Request Problem at Python & symbol in string breaks the all string

Tags: python, xml, request, response, symbols

I have problem about xml request at PYTHON. I need to send the url at below

https://catalogonuevo.icerbrakes.com/Image/GetImage?idProducto=140376&pixelsX=462&logo=images%2FLogoIcerBrakes.jpg

it sends before & symbol

https://catalogonuevo.icerbrakes.com/Image/GetImage?idProducto=140376

img_src = "https://catalogonuevo.icerbrakes.com/Image/GetImage?idProducto=140376&pixelsX=462&logo=images%2FLogoIcerBrakes.jpg
"

Want to send this complete url :

https://catalogonuevo.icerbrakes.com/Image/GetImage?idProducto=140376&pixelsX=462&logo=images%2FLogoIcerBrakes.jpg

But it breaks after & symbol.

payload= "data[Product][pro_STOCK_CODE]=" + product_no  + "&&" + "data[Product][pro_NAME]=" + name  +  "&&"  +  "data[Product][cat_ID]="+ ids +"&&" +  "data[Image][0]=" + image

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}

response2 = requests.request("POST", url2, headers=headers, data=payload.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML, `&` has to be escaped as `&amp;` unless used to introduce an [`&entity;`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references) reference.

### See also

- [escaping ampersands in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38229796/290085)
- [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/290085)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've replaced them but still doesn't work. After request i looked at response, there is still a break.

Comment: Update your question with the exact new URL.  All `&&`'s should be changed to `&amp;`'s.